# VS Code Typescript Build Error on modified @types/nouislider .ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nouislider

I had to rebuild my laptop and am trying to get my company's typescript project to build.

I used `npm i --save-dev @types/nouislider` and then I have to edit the ts file to add a missing property.  I added `target` property to the `noUiSlider` interface.

[image]

When I try to build, I get this error, but you can see from the tooltip, that VS Code 'knows' about the target property.

[image]

This code is working on my desktop and I can't see a difference in VS Code versions or settings.  Not really knowing where to look to solve this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems VS had some sort of build cache or something.  I renamed the property in the modified `index.d.ts` file to `target2`.  Then recompiled and obviously `.target` was incorrect and VS Code suggested `target2`.  I changed to `target2` and built successfully.  I then just changed the `index.d.ts` back to `target` and repeated the process successfully.